# TFS 2013 web access errors

Tags: tfs, migration, tfs-web-access

Our group recently completed an upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 during a server migration. After completing the migration we are unable to use a number of the web-accessable features and get the following error `TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized.`. I have read a few links where other people have encountered a similar error but have so far been unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you move to 2013 RTM or 2013 Update 4? You should be on Update 4.

Comment: This is more of a support question andbi recommend that you contact Microsoft directly...

Comment: @MrHinsh thank you, I had not seen that a newer release was out. I am performing an update to see if this helps resolve the issue.

Comment: @MrHinsh I have installed the update and can verify that I still encounter the same error.